Skip lines with JSON document that cause "ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value" in pd.read_json(..., lines=True)
Consider a document btc_transactions.json that contains the following data:

{"txid":"00a5b60bf38d0605a7ed65c557722e42c1637e1dade80e37b7fc73cea3b67d9b","consensus_time":"2013-07-14T07:07:24.000000000Z","tx_position":"1058687963627546","n_balance_updates":"4","amount":"0.7","block_hash":"000000000000004b880aa75d36e2586b8570b8e15dc192f33e5e834bf51fd06a","height":"246495","miner_time":"2013-07-14T07:43:12.000000000Z","min_chain_sequence_number":"1058687963627730","max_chain_sequence_number":"1058687963627733","version":"1","physical_size":"227","consensus_size":"908","fee":"0.0001"}
{"txid":"991cbe2565efb9712d55db1683548625403b325ea9a9dfed906fce1fb9bd1941","consensus_time":"2013-07-14T07:07:24.000000000Z","tx_position":"1058687963627547","n_balance_updates":"4","amount":"0.66434783","block_hash":"000000000000004b880aa75d36e2586b8570b8e15dc192f33e5e834bf51fd06a","height":"246495","miner_time":"2013-07-14T07:43:12.000000000Z","min_chain_sequence_number":"1058687963627734","max_chain_sequence_number":"1058687963627737","version":"1","physical_size":"258","consensus_size":"1032","fee":"0.0001"}
{"txid":"49044a76c558afad2b8f3bb895c958922e08bdf47931a60110ff9{"txid":"5038df9cc96824f7b990f4cc9405a5babe4a742e79b0c325e0487033b78d1e85","consensus_time":"2013-07-16T06:43:24.000000000Z","tx_position":"1060118187737455","n_balance_updates":"4","amount":"0.64502946","block_hash":"000000000000004e79a680599d4e3a2f3fc244d7ef7238666fa52418008d53a0","height":"246828","miner_time":"2013-07-16T07:33:26.000000000Z","min_chain_sequence_number":"1060118187739070","max_chain_sequence_number":"1060118187739073","version":"1","physical_size":"227","consensus_size":"908","fee":"0.0001"}
{"txid":"c785ea0649bf6df832afa9e58b5719967b8d30eef4878fc0bb6302e8b8fc0e31","consensus_time":"2013-07-14T07:12:41.000000000Z","tx_position":"1058692258594819","n_balance_updates":"4","amount":"400","block_hash":"0000000000000022847171b0b5a2e0c0ddf2444ef2dd6925c8a85891f1199e08","height":"246496","miner_time":"2013-07-14T08:09:32.000000000Z","min_chain_sequence_number":"1058692258594827","max_chain_sequence_number":"1058692258594830","version":"1","physical_size":"225","consensus_size":"900","fee":"0"}

The penultimate line is an invalid JSON document while the other 3 lines are valid (there are  many more lines and files which I want to process using dask).
Loading this data with pd.read_json(..., lines=True) fails with ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding object value.
Is there an opportunity to skip these lines similar to the behavior of pandas.read_csv's on_bad_lines parameter?
I believe this enhancement request aimed for   something similar but it looks like it did not come to pass.
I am aware of this question with the same point of departure that could also benefit from a potential solution.
Importantly, the faulty line is not causing an encoding related error.
E.g. the option encoding_errors='ignore' is not resolving the problem and neither is a switch to the pyarrow engine. However, the latter yields a more precise error message

pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: JSON parse error: Missing a comma or '}' after an object member. in row 2


Is there any reason not to use a try-except?

You mean try: pd.read_json(...) except: ...? That would skip the entire file while I only want to skip invalid JSON documents within said file if I understood you correctly.

One possible solution is to pre-process the json file to remove invalid lines using a try...except, and then load the valid lines into pandas:
def get_valid_json_lines(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                json.loads(line)
                yield line
            except json.JSONDecodeError:
                continue


file_path = "btc_transactions.json"
valid_lines = "".join(get_valid_json_lines(file_path))
df = pd.read_json(valid_lines, lines=True)

                                                txid            consensus_time       tx_position  ...  physical_size  consensus_size     fee
0  00a5b60bf38d0605a7ed65c557722e42c1637e1dade80e... 2013-07-14 07:07:24+00:00  1058687963627546  ...            227             908  0.0001
1  991cbe2565efb9712d55db1683548625403b325ea9a9df... 2013-07-14 07:07:24+00:00  1058687963627547  ...            258            1032  0.0001
2  c785ea0649bf6df832afa9e58b5719967b8d30eef4878f... 2013-07-14 07:12:41+00:00  1058692258594819  ...            225             900  0.0000


Yes, that works but I believe it is cumbersome for many (large) files. In my case dask would call pd.read_json forcing me to preprocess all files beforehand which is not efficient. However, I think pre-processing is currently the only way. Maybe I will go ahead and try to make a PR of the Github issue I mentioned in the question.

@TLeitzbach To my knowledge, yes, if you're using pandas pre-processing the json files seems to be the only way. I don't have experience with dask, but maybe you could use something like read_text to preprocess files in chunks to make it more efficient.
